# The 465 Arrangement

Tags: code-golf

Here's the challenge. Write some code to output all the integers in a range. Sounds easy, but here's the tricky part. It will start with the lowest number, then the highest. Then the lowest number which isn't yet in the array. Then the highest which isn't yet in it.

### Example:

Lets take 1 to 5 as our start

The numbers are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

We take the first, so [1]. Remaining numbers are [2, 3, 4, 5]. 
We take the last, new array is [1, 5]. Remaining numbers are [2, 3, 4]. 
We take the first, new array is [1, 5, 2]. Remaining numbers are [3, 4]. 
We take the last, new array is [1, 5, 2, 4]. Remaining numbers are [3]. 
We take the first, new array is [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]. No numbers remaining, we're done.
Output [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]

### Rules:

- This is code golf, write it in the fewest bytes, any language.
- No standard loopholes.
- Links to an online interpreter, please? (E.g. https://tio.run/)
- Two inputs, both integers. Low end of range, and high end of range.
- I don't mind what the data type of the output is, but it must show the numbers in the correct order.

### Examples

Low: 4
High: 6
Result:
4
6
5

---

Low: 1
High: 5
Result:
1
5
2
4
3

---

Low: -1
High: 1
Result:
-1
1
0

---

Low: -1
high: 2
Result:
-1
2
0
1

---

Low: -50
High: 50
Result:
-50
50
-49
49
-48
48
-47
47
-46
46
-45
45
-44
44
-43
43
-42
42
-41
41
-40
40
-39
39
-38
38
-37
37
-36
36
-35
35
-34
34
-33
33
-32
32
-31
31
-30
30
-29
29
-28
28
-27
27
-26
26
-25
25
-24
24
-23
23
-22
22
-21
21
-20
20
-19
19
-18
18
-17
17
-16
16
-15
15
-14
14
-13
13
-12
12
-11
11
-10
10
-9
9
-8
8
-7
7
-6
6
-5
5
-4
4
-3
3
-2
2
-1
1
0

---

Happy golfing!

Comment: [Almost duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82294/194) (the difference being that this one requires reversing the second half before merging).

Comment: is the input always going to be in the order of low end, high end?

Comment: @Sumner18 yes. The community here is dead-set against input validation, and I haven’t asked for a reverse-order input, so we can assume it’ll always be low - high.

Comment: Are warnings allowed? Sorry, I'm working on a solution and can get a very short solution in my preferred language if warnings are allowed.

Comment: @Sumner18 How these challenges usually work is that we don't care how invalid inputs are handled. Your code is only judged to be successful by how it deals with valid inputs (i.e. both are integers, the first is lower than the second)

Comment: @AJFaraday: you should add a note to the main post indicating that X will be always strictly lower than Y (i.e. X != Y), I missed this comment ;)

Comment: @AJFaraday, are you saying that we *must* take the lower integer as the first input? Or are we free to *choose* which order to take them in? I suggest the latter.

Answer (score 15):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```r
function(a,b)rbind(a:b,b:a)[a:b-a+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XdHNSsNAFMXxfZ/igJsGc2DunZl8CD6JuGiVQjcVij5//VeRYsMvEG7ISXLP@XJ4vhy@Tm@fx4/Tdjfuh/P@eHrf7p724/5pN7xw4d1jvF4O2zZOg67Hg5om9c1hG2P/G4W6khuVsWOM4Xfs4E75neVtliqK67SXsZfhZ9qL4LYKbovgNgtuk@DWBbcmuFXBjdemNrodhLUQ3Irgugqui@A6C66T4NoFVz6dzFqFu7CagmsIrkVwroJzEZyz4JwEJ7sgM5twF5ZVcKbgZBdkZhEcq@BYBMcsOCbB0YW7sGiCowqOFBzsnMxgxUXyKpG58ACnZwmeRIX/w2hAlMjSRI/8pwSnaOvaGUWKKi/f)

- -1 byte thanks to @user2390246
- -1 byte thanks to @Kirill L.

Exploiting the fact that R stores matrices column-wise

Comment: Using `rbind` is much better than my approach, but you can save 1 byte by using `[seq(a:b)]` instead of `unique`.

Comment: You're right, I missed the comment where has been specified that a < b (never equal), so we can use `seq(a:b)`

Comment: @digEmAll My solution was essentially a literal interpretation of the puzzle, I never would have even thought of doing something such as this. Impressive, have an upvote!

Comment: [-1 more](https://tio.run/##XdHNSsNAFMXxfZ/igJsGc2DunZl8CD6JuGiVQjcVij5//VeRYsMvEG7ISXLP@XJ4vhy@Tm@fx4/Tdjfuh/P@eHrf7p724/5pN7xw4d1jvF4O2zZOg67Hg5om9c1hG2P/G4W6khuVsWOM4Xfs4E75neVtliqK67SXsZfhZ9qL4LYKbovgNgtuk@DWBbcmuFXBjdemNrodhLUQ3Irgugqui@A6C66T4NoFVz6dzFqFu7CagmsIrkVwroJzEZyz4JwEJ7sgM5twF5ZVcKbgZBdkZhEcq@BYBMcsOCbB0YW7sGiCowqOFBzsnMxgxUXyKpG58ACnZwmeRIX/w2hAlMjSRI/8pwSnaOvaGUWKKi/f)

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
a%b=a:take(b-a)(b:(a+1)%(b-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBCoAgEEbhfaf4FwkzRJCRLYQOM5KQZBbV/c1t0fJ98Ba5Vh9jzqLcJPaW1ZNrhclZkkazKqWZ8yYhYcK8VzjOkG7UIMUYML5Bw7yByg79Y/3XTMcwXZUf)

Comment: Dammit! I have just found the exact same solution. Oh well

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65</s> <s>64</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Robert S.

-4 more thanks to digEmAll

```r
x=scan();z=x:x[2];while(sum(z|1)){cat(z[1],"");z=rev(z[-1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTusq2wqoi2ijWujwjMydVo7g0V6OqxlBTszo5sUSjKtowVkdJCaSqKLUMyNU1jNWs/W/EZcr1HwA)

Comment: You can replace `length(z)` with `sum(z|1)` to save 1 byte :)

Comment: I don't understand how that works but I guess it does. sum(z|1) seems like it would always evaluate to at least 1, which would cause the while loop to loop endlessly. but apparently not

Comment: z is a vector. each element of that vector is `|`ed with 1. Which is always equal to 1. When you take the sum, you have a vector filled with `TRUE`s so the result is equal to the length of the vector. If the vector is empty, you the is nothing to `|` with so the output vector is `logical(0)`. When you take that sum, it's 0

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
a#b|a>b=a:b#(a-1)|a<b=a:b#(a+1)|1>0=[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5qSbRLsk20SpJWSNR11CzJtEGxtMG8gztDGyjE2P/5yZm5inYKhQUZeaVKKgoaOgaayooKxj/BwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:[a]*(a==b)or[a]+f(b,a-cmp(a,b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw7CoAwEATQ3lNsuasrGDEWQk4iFhslKGgSgo2njx@s3sAME69zDb7N2ZldDrsICNthlKlEMcZSSE@uHFqWej4iPi1RdiG9O9g8jNhxTwyoWL/UitVv@6kb1g1NQwEQ0@ZPcN9JvgE)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>59</s> 48 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)(($z=0..($b-$a))|%{$a+$_;$b-$_})[$z]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJU0NDpcrWQE9PQyVJVyVRU7NGtVolUVsl3hrEj6/VjFapiv3//7@GrqHmfyMA)

<s>*(Seems long...)*</s>

Takes input `$a` and `$b`, constructs the range `0 .. ($b-$a)`, stores that into `$z`, then loops through that range. The looping through that range is just used as a counter to ensure we get enough iterations. Each iteration, we put `$a` and `$b` on the pipeline with addition/subtraction. That gives us something like `1,5,2,4,3,3,4,2,5,1` so we need to slice into that from `0` up to the `$b-$a` (i.e., the count) of the original array so we're only left with the appropriate elements. That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

*-11 bytes thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJU0NDpcrWQE9PQyVJVyVRU7NGtVolUVsl3hrEj6/VjFapiv3//7@GrqHmfyMA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Ah, I like that `$b-$a` trick -- that's clever!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ŸDvć,R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6A6XsiPtOkH//0frmhromBrEAgA)

**Explanation**

```
Ÿ        # push range [min ... max]
 D       # duplicate
  v      # for each element in the copy
   ć,    # extract and print the head of the original list
     R   # and then reverse it
```

Comment: Ÿ2ä`R.ι non iterative using interleave, but this is still much better.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I tried a non-iterative solution first, but it was even worse since I didn't know about `.ι` ;)

Comment: Similar as what I had in mind, so obvious +1 from me. I do like your alternative 7-byter as well through, @MagicOctopusUrn. :)

Comment: With arguments "12" and "35" it returns the array members largest-smallest pairs instead of smallest-largest pairs: 35 12 34 13 33 14 32 15 31 16 30 17 29 18 28 19 27 20 26 21 25 22 24 23

Comment: @KristianWilliams: Seems to be [working](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6A6XsiPtOkH//xubchkaAQA) for me.

Comment: Maybe specify that the input is `high\nlow` when you also edit in the explanation. But `35\n12` indeed seems to work fine.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I switched to a pair instead as that felt more intuitive anyways :)

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't aware it expected high/low input. With the new pairing it's more intuitive and works as expected.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm a bit late to the party but here's a [non-iterative solution in 5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181180/56470)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
òV
íUs w)c vUl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CmMK7Da0OLFco1kxXKQnP@/9c1NeAyNQAA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CmMIXDa0MPbw3jSlYoC835/1/X1IDL1AAA), using the same approach.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>{for(;a<=b;Write(a+(b>a++?b--+"":"")));}
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to dana!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXouOYXJKZnwdi2tml2f5PtLVLsrWrTssv0rBOtLFNsg4vyixJ1UjU1kiyS9TWtk/S1dVWUrJSUtLU1LSu/W/NlaZhqKlhqmnNBVbok5mXqqEJFTXRtP4PAA)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 65 bytes

```cs
void z(int a,int b){if(a<=b){Write(a+(b>a?b+"":""));z(a+1,b-1);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LD8zRaFKIzOvRCFRB0QmaVZnpmkk2tgCGeFFmSWpGonaGkl2ifZJ2kpKVkpKmprWVUAhQ50kXUNN69ra/1UahjqmmtZcYMU@mXmpGkAOSNBE0/o/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
É╓ÅìΔà▲
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=90d68f8dff851e&i=4+6%0A1+5%0A-1+1%0A-1+2%0A-50+50&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes

```r
function(x,y,z=x:y)matrix(c(z,rev(z)),2,,T)[seq(z)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSp8q2wqpSMzexpCizQiNZo0qnKLVMo0pTU8dIRydEM7o4tRDIi/2fpmGiY6bJlaZhqGMKonQNdQyhtBGYNjXQMTXQ/A8A)

Explanation:
For a sequence `x:y` of length `N`, create a two-by-N matrix consisting of the sequence x:y in the top row and y:x in the bottom row `matrix(c(z,rev(z)),2,,T)`. If we select the first `N` elements of the matrix `[seq(z)]`, they will be chosen by column, giving the required output.

[Outgolfed by digEmAll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179869/66252)

Comment: I just posted a very similar approach 30 seconds before you :D

Comment: @digEmAll Yes, but yours is a lot better!

Answer (score 4):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 19 bytes

```
#|B-A+1&A+k-1,B-k+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X7nGSddR21DNUTtb11DHSTdb2/D/f11DBUMA)

Note that it does not work on TIO right now because TIO's interpreter is not up to date.

### Explanation

```
#|B-A+1&A+k-1,B-k+1
                      A is the first input, B is the second input
#|B-A+1               n = B - A + 1
       &              Print the first n terms of the sequence
                      k starts at 1 and increments whenever we return to the first term
        A+k-1,         Terms alternate between A + k - 1 and
              B-k+1     B - k + 1
                       increment k
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 39 bytes

```
f(a:b)=a:f(reverse b)
f x=x
a#b=f[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bci9CoAgFAbQ3af4oAYdCotsCHySaLiSkvSLRfT21lp0xjPQPtppitFxaozQ1Dge7GnDbmEEc7j0xSgx2rWU56aLM/kFGv3KsAW/HEjBE4EK9TsKqHfwrHj258rvKSmgJIs3)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 30 bytes

```
l%h=l:take(h-l)(h:(l+1)%(h-1))
```

Usage: `3%7` gives `[3,7,4,6,5]

For the inputs `l, h` the function calls recursively with the inputs `l+1, h-1`, and adds `l,h` to the beggining.
Instead of any halting condition, the code uses `take(h-l)` to shorten the sequence to the right length (which would otherwise be an infinite sequence of increasing and decreasing numbers).

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

This is my first time golfing!

```
f[a_,b_]:=(c=a~Range~b;Drop[c~Riffle~Reverse@c,a-b-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOjFeJyk@1spWI9k2KDEvPTU6UScp1tqlKL8gOigzLS0nNTpZJyi1LLWoONUhOVYnUTdJ1zBW839AUWZeiUNatImOglksF4xnqKNgiuDpArmGqFyj2P8A)

Saved 2 bytes using infix notation.

Explanation:

```
f[a_,b_]:=                                   \function of two variables
c=a~Range~b;                                 \list of integers from a to b 
                           Reverse@c         \same list in reverse
                  c~Riffle~Reverse@c         \interleave the two lists
             Drop[c~Riffle~Reverse@c,a-b-1]  \drop last |a-b-1| elements (note a-b-1 < 0)
```

Alternatively, we could use `Take[...,b-a+1]` for the same result.

Tests:

```
f[4, 6]
f[1, 5]
f[-1, 1]
f[-1, 2]
```

Ouput:

```
{4, 6, 5}
{1, 5, 2, 4, 3}
{-1, 1, 0}
{-1, 2, 0, 1}
```

Comment: The "Try it online" link returns a 403. "Sorry, you do not have permission to access this item."

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I updated the link

Comment: note that on TIO you can place header and footer code in the text boxes above and below the actual code box. This makes the code look cleaner, as well as allow you to take advantage the PPCG answer formatter (esc-s-g). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOjFeJyk@1spWI9k2KDEvPTU6UScp1tqlKL8gOigzLS0nNTpZJyi1LLWoONUhOVYnUTdJ1zBW839AUWZeiUNatImOglksF4xnqKNgiuDpArmGqFyj2P8A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing much appreciated, I had never used it before!

Answer (score 4):

## JVM bytecode (OpenJDK asmtools JASM), 449 bytes

```
enum b{const #1=Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(I)V;static Method a:(II)V stack 2 locals 4{getstatic java/lang/System.out:"Ljava/io/PrintStream;";astore 3;ldc 0;istore 2;l:iload 2;ldc 1;if_icmpeq t;aload 3;iload 0;invokevirtual #1;iinc 0,1;iinc 2,1;goto c;t:aload 3;iload 1;invokevirtual #1;iinc 1,-1;iinc 2,-1;c:aload 3;ldc 32;i2c;invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream.print:(C)V;iload 0;iload 1;if_icmpne l;aload 3;iload 0;invokevirtual #1;return;}}
```

Ungolfed (and slightly cleaner)

```
 enum b {    
    public static Method "a":(II)V stack 5 locals 4 {
        getstatic "java/lang/System"."out":"Ljava/io/PrintStream;";
        astore 3;
        ldc 0;
        istore 2;
    loop:
        iload 2;
        ldc 1;
        if_icmpeq true;
    false:
        aload 3;
        iload 0;
        invokevirtual "java/io/PrintStream"."print":"(I)V";
        iinc 0,1;
        iinc 2,1;
        goto cond;
    true:
        aload 3;
        iload 1;
        invokevirtual "java/io/PrintStream"."print":"(I)V";
        iinc 1,-1;
        iinc 2,-1;
        goto cond;
    cond:
        iload 0;
        iload 1;
        if_icmpne loop;
        aload 3;
        iload 0;
        invokevirtual "java/io/PrintStream"."print":"(I)V";
        return;
    }
}
```

Standalone function, needs to be called from Java as `b.a(num1,num2)`.

### Explanation

This code uses the method parameters as variables, as well as a boolean in local #3 deciding which number to output. Each loop iteration either the left or right is output, and that number is incremented for the left or decremented for the right. Loop continues until both numbers are equal, then that number is output.

...I have a distinct feeling I'm *massively* outgunned on the byte count

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
↨_x^─▀
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9R24r4irhHUxoeTWv4/99EwYzLUMGUS9dQwRBEGHHpmhoomBoAAA)

### Explanation with `(1, 5)`

```
↨        inclusive range from a to b    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 _       duplicate TOS                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  x      reverse int/array/string       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
   ^     zip top two elements on stack  [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
    ─    flatten array                  [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
     ▀   unique elements of string/list [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

The reason why this works is due to the fact that all elements in the output should be unique, so the unique elements operator will filter out the second half of the array, producing the correct output.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 21 bytes

```apl
⌈⊢+.5×-+∘(⌽×¯1*)∘⍳1+-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R24RHPR2PuhZp65kenq6r/ahjhsajnr2Hpx9ab6ilCeQ96t1sqK37/7@ZQpqCCZcpkDTkMgSSQHkuIyhtagBmmBr8yy8oyczPK/6vWwwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 7 bytes

Takes input as an array.

```
rõ
ÊÆÔv
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cvUKysbUdg==&input=WzEsNV0=) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cvUKysbUdg==&input=WwpbNCw2XQpbMSw1XQpbLTEsMV0KWy0xLDJdClstNTAsNTBdCl0KLW1S)

```
         :Implicit input of array U=[low,high]
r        :Reduce by
 õ       :  Inclusive, reversed range (giving the range [high,low])
\n       :Reassign to U
Ê        :Length
 Æ       :Map the range [0,Ê)
  Ô      :  Reverse U
   v     :  Remove the first element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
&:t"1&)P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X82qRMlQTTPg/39DLlMA)

#### Explanation

```
&:      % Take two inputs (implicit). Two-input range
t       % Duplicate
"       % For each
  1&)   %   Push first element, then an array with the rest
  P     %   Reverse array
        % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 52 bytes

```forth
: f 2dup - 1+ 0 do dup . i 2 mod 2* 1- - swap loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCgIxFEP3PcVjlsov0@q4cMC7iKUqKP1UZY5ff@kieYSQ5FK/D7nnjtbOZGL6KULYM5MKPXmeRN4lEXcEsfazXZVXKcpqIx2jA74O8xPIhcnubpXVuRNH1C0E84B0xIFlRkza/g)

#### Explanation

Loop from 0 to (End - Start). Place End and Start on top of the stack.

Each Iteration:

- Output the current number
- Add (or subtract) 1 from the current number
- Switch the current number with the other number

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start new word definition
  2dup -      \ get the size of the range (total number of integers)
  1+ 0        \ add 1 to the size because forth loops are [Inclusive, Exclusive) 
  do          \ start counted loop from 0 to size+1
    dup .     \ output the current top of the stack
    i 2 mod   \ get the index of the loop modulus 2
    2* 1-     \ convert from 0,1 to -1,1
    -         \ subtract result from top of stack (adds 1 to lower bound and subtracts 1 from upper)
    swap      \ swap the top two stack numbers 
  loop        \ end the counted loop
;             \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 40 bytes

```
l=>g=h=>h>l?[l++,h--,...g(h)]:h<l?[]:[l]
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##LchLDoMgFEDROavoEOKDSFM6MEIXgi/BWBUNBVObRldPP3F0bu7cvtu1e07Li8d07/Ogc9Bm1F4bb8LNhqIAzzkIIUbqGVa@/l6sbMDcpbim0IuQRmoJsRe4IhArQf3gEuTh@a8qQZVICIpHu1BqN9iRaTPQjdGdiTlN0cHJHdXEJjqWPw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
f(a,b)=[a:b b:-1:a]'[1:1+b-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//8/TSNRJ0nTNjrRKkkhyUrX0CoxVj3a0MpQO0k3MfZ/QVFmXklOnkaahomOmaYmF4JvqGOKwtc11DFEFzBCFTA10DE10NT8DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
⟦₂{∅|b↔↰T&hg,T}
```

Input is a 2-element list [lo, hi]. Note that underscore is used for negative numbers. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@amqofdbTWJD1qm/KobUOIWka6Tkjt///R8YY6prH/IwA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₂               2-argument inclusive range: [1,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5]
  {           }  Call this recursive predicate to calculate the output:
   ∅               Base case: the input is empty list; nothing to do
    |              Otherwise (recursive case):      [1,2,3,4,5]
     b             Behead the input list            [2,3,4,5]
      ↔            Reverse                          [5,4,3,2]
       ↰           Call the predicate recursively   [5,2,4,3]
        T          Label the result T
         &         Also, with the input list,
          h        Take the head                    1
           g       Wrap it in a list                [1]
            ,T     Append T from earlier            [1,5,2,4,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ŸÂ.ιÙ
```

Takes input as upper first.

Explanation:

```
ŸÂ.ιÙ   //full program
Ÿ       //push [min .. max]                stack: [[4, 5, 6]]
 Â      //push range and reversed range    stack: [[4, 5, 6], [6, 5, 4]]
  .ι    //interleave                       stack: [[4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4]]
    Ù   //deduplicate                      stack: [[4, 6, 5]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I7DTXrndh6e@f@/GZcJAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 52 bytes

```java
(l,h,o)->{for(int i=0;l<=h;i^=1)o.add(i<1?l++:h--);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xa8MwEIV3/4obpUYWydClilOyZGqnjKUF1bbic2XJSOeUEPzbXdlJoVDQIe59d@9dq886b6uvCbveB4I29XIgtPJBZf80M7iS0LsZllbHCK8aHVwzAHRUB6PLGg5LD3D2WIFhCYAVM4dG/PF6wUjguUqzY6p@@LRYQiRN6Vt2u9mbHSmgO729gw6nyO/eKcQUE7OiEZ7nu6vxYQnCYq3stmgUfhQb7qWuKobbzbNdrZ6aPOdqnNRicEsfCApw9TfsQ9CXWWP8xo00LH9ci/Tmsbt6vESqO5kE2aeryDr2C8dsnH4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 45 bytes

```
=h(I,A)
{I<=A:{I} {I<A:{A} ->h(I+1,A-1)}}->->
```

<s>(I don't think there's an online interpreter for Ink, sorry)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/m@iY2ala5ehAaQ1de249LgMdUzBAkAaIhCja6hjCBYCMRBiRjAxI6DYf9sMDU8dR02uak8bW0eras9aBSALyHCsVQAp89Q21HHUNdSsrdW1A6r@DwA)

Defines a stitch called h, which takes two arguments I and A, which are the bounds of the range.

Outputs by printing values, separated by spaces, to stdout.

## Explanation

```
=h(min, max) // Define the stitch.
{min <= max:{min}/* print min unless it's greater than max */{min < max: {max} /*Also print max if it's greater than min*/->h(min+1, max-1)/*Then divert, with the arguments changed*/}}
->-> // If we didn't divert earlier, divert to wherever the stitch was called from
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ln`, 37 bytes

```perl
@.=$_..<>;say shift@.,$/,pop@.while@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99Bz1YlXk/Pxs66OLFSoTgjM63EQU9HRV@nIL/AQa88IzMn1UHv/39dI1MuI9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/uvm5AEA)

Comment: [33bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l1dbGzro4sVKlRlfXXiVVV9dKJV5buzSvJDNHJd5OJfX/f11jLqN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/uvm5AEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
rạṂ¥Þ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//cuG6oeG5gsKlw54s////LTUw/zUw)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
{.iF_B}F
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7B.iF_B%7DF&input=-50%2C+50&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
{.iF_B}F
      }FQ  Generate the range between the (implicit) inputs.
 .iF_B     Interleave it with its reverse.
{          Deduplicate.
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, bytes <s>17, 13</s>, 26

4 bytes saved thank to Adám  plus 13 bytes see Jonah's comment

```
(⍴m)↑∊m,¨⌽m←(1↓m)+0,⍳-/m←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5rPOrdkqv5qG3io46uXJ1DKx717M0FymoYPmqbnKupbaDzqHezrj5ICKjxP1DL/zQuUwOFQ@tNDQA)

Explanation:

```
m←(1↓m)+0,⍳-/m←⎕ Prompts high end of range followed by low end and generates vector

∊m,¨⌽m Reverse the vector, pair elements from both vectors and flatten.           

(⍴m)↑ Select the elements to the length of the original vector
```

Comment: Can you not replace `[1.1]` with `⍪`? And if you can't do that, then surely `∊m,¨⌽m` works for the same byte count, no?

Comment: @Adám No I cannot use ⍪ unless I already have a single row matrix which I would then have to transpose. This has knock on effects to the final selection. On the second point agreed but again a style point give same byte count.

Comment: Doesn't monadic `⍪` cause `⌽m` to be a 1-column matrix, and then `m,` pairs up scalars of `m` with rows of `⌽m`? [Try!](https://tryapl.org/?a=1%202%203%2C%u236A4%205%206&run) And `∊m,¨⌽m` is surely shorter than `m,[1.1]⌽m`!

Comment: @Adám From the manual: Join two arrays. The default for ⍪ is along the first dimension; the default for , is along the last dimension. There is no monadic option. ∊m,¨⌽m is indeed 4 bytes shorter. Thanks

Comment: Your explanations are a bit behind. I would describe `∊m,¨⌽m` as zipping and your last line has `,m` which doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Adám. Thanks. Not familiar with zipping. Hopefully my version makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't the input need to be the low and high numbers of the range?

Comment: @Jonah Missed that bit :( costs me 7bytes over simple vector!

Comment: yeah it's a shame, same thing with my J answer

Comment: @Jonah It gets worse when I have to handle negative low end values. Doubles the code :( Nearly always the case when we need to do input pre-processing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 48 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a b|a<>b=[a: $b(a+sign(b-a))]=[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLJVEhqSbRxi7JNjrRSkElSSNRuzgzPU8jSTdRUzMWKBj7P7gkEajeVkFFQdfUQMHU4P@/5LScxPTi/7qePv9dKvMSczOTiwE)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 35 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b,s=1)=>a-b?a+[,f(b,a+s,-s)]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctLDsIgFIXheVfBENJLU4w4sKGOXAVhcEHwkaaYXmJ09ViNjr4/Jzk3fCCF5Xovcs6nWGsyHMEDGSXMiNIfsLWQuAdsCSQJt8daIpWAFJlhtrFb2DlorAL9QSpQPzdfdQ@6X8sNzf/XpbwcMVw4t094OcHMyEKeKU@xm/KZJ77OQoihvgE)

Thanks to Arnauld, 1 byte saved.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```ruby
f=->a,b{a>b ?[]:[a,b]|f[a+1,b-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5RJ6k60S5JwT461ioayImtSYtO1DbUSdI1jK39H80VbaJjFqvDFW2oYwqidA11DKG0EZg2NdAxNYjlitVLTUzOqK4BmlBToJAGNqn2PwA)

Recursive version with 3 bytes saved by G B.

#### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{d=*c=a..b;c.map{d.reverse!.pop}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcy7CoAgFADQ3a@oNW4XjWwJ@xFxUDNaIjEKwvx2e9B0thN2c@ZJ5HrQYOIoKis0ouktLtrHEYM7XNhciX71KWVJZAudAiIZ8JeaAfttPjkFThVR6LSd4/Wsly8m@ahSvgE)

Non-recursive version.

Answer (score 2):

## Cubix, 16 bytes

```
;w(.II>sO-?@;)^/
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=O3coLklJPnNPLT9AOyleLw==&input=MSA1&speed=10)

#### Cubified

```
    ; w
    ( .
I I > s O - ? @
; ) ^ / . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

#### Explanation

Basically, this moves the two bounds closer together one step at a time until they meet.  Each time through the loop, we `s`wap the bounds, `O`utput, take the difference, and increment with `)` or decrement with `(` based on the sign.

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 48 bytes

```
(d f(q((A B)(c A(i(e A B)()(f B((i(l A B)a s)A 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRSFNo1BDw1HBSVMjWcFRI1MjVQHM0dRIU3DSAPJzwPxEhWJNRwXD/0BRQwVTTS4grVGsYKBgaKAJwv8B)

#### Explanation

The code defines a recursive function `f` that takes two arguments `A` and `B`, which are initially the lower and upper bounds of the range.

- Base case: if `A = B`, return a list containing the single element `A`
- Recursive case: prepend `A` to the result of a recursive call:

  - If `A < B`, recurse with arguments `B` and `A+1`
  - If `A > B`, recurse with arguments `B` and `A-1`

For example, with initial arguments 1 and 5:

```
Value   Next call
1       5, 2
5       2, 4
2       4, 3
4       3, 3
3       Return
```

with a resulting list of `(1 5 2 4 3)`.

Somewhat ungolfed:

```
(load lib/utilities)

(def f
  (lambda (A B)
    (cons A
      (if (equal? A B)
        nil
        (f B
          ((if (less? A B) add2 sub2)
            A
            1))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes

A recursive function, call as `f(low, high)`. As an extra 0-byte bonus, if you call `f(high, low)` the opposite arrangement is produced.

```c
f(x,y){printf("%i ",x);x-y&&f(y,x+1-2*(x>y));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NboMwEIXX4RQjKpAN4wqi0EVJc4Kou67SLJDBYImayDgqKOLqde2kUbPw/Ph9b0bDWcu5tYJMONPLSUtlBAkjCSFOtJzYHMeCzDilOVsnZNrNlJaLfZKK9@e6ge1o6roRz90uCJwVviqpiC84Ah/U6Iqu0pAklW5HeglWYtAEPCDhDfLSpS1wl9IUKDh95bV@QOhk6brHGc3JaP/XD846Gm2GnvixB3lEiL2KkFFPdPKfSNOb8v6x3990B9zvPEQSI3l8ddf@Lb36BXlo7uynCq/mxT3dmLNWkJXBYu0GX2yOhWU55j6sLSsyLLIfLvqqHS37/gU)

### Degolf

```c
f(x,y)
{
  printf("%i ",x); // Print the value of x
  x-y&& // If x-y == 0, the && operator shorts and the
        // recursion ends.
    f(y,x+1-2*(x>y)); // Adjust x by 1 towards y, and
                      // recurse with x and y swapped.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```cs
a=>b=>{var s="";for(;b>=a;)s+=a+" "+(b==a++?"":b--+" ");return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcwxiwIxEAXgfn/FkCph3QNFLYzJFQdWCoKFdZKNEliTYyYriPjb12xjpfKKecwHz1HjEvqhpxDPcLhR9hdZuc4QwR7TGc3lXgH897YLDiibXM41hRZ2JkQuRgTY9NGtQ8yTV6GMZVBraEENRmmr9P1qEEgxJk8JubRaGSmoVqZmwGpuVWn1L2Mr2zTjS0j0uccIJB@DrP5SpNT5nyOG7Lchet7yueBLId7bVPDFJ2sKTr/hbMRHyfAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

```hs
x?y=take(y+1-x).map head$iterate(reverse.tail)[x..y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJNa@MwFEX3/hWP0IVNfEMk2f1YGNPNwEB3swxZmEQloWmSRmon@fWZe02gw2wGfOznJ@voWU@bIb3F3e56PfeXLg9vsbxMHc7V7H042iYO67ttjqchx/IUv@IpxVketrtqcZ7NLstrjikn62xRNv19bYumNj7aZVVb6fqWGcfX2nxtHApjvoSreqYX4I3X/Dvrb1k@5xy7DbTzqm/nGtJdoHmi8EnBI4NHBQ8MHhSwAIGG6wo0XFqgCQyCAtXjFXAxgYZWgUCrQKBVINAqEGgVCLQKBP2UzIFWgUCrQKBVINAq4GkV8LQKeFoFPK0CXnsls6dVwNMq4GkV8NogmT2tAo5WAUergKNVwNEq4GgVcLQKOFoFHK0CTg2R2Wn3ZaZUXiplpVDO@7HJaMfOohlbC22Aahqb993ZZVGsDzolVq5qixXPyvpQ2PbVonWdrSxv4r4wO37mX/n0src7mxyHlGxi06mlzeE3v2E0sa7/KxcLi7sU/5n44/nny38nFu/Dds8yUvz4jPtV5MRXnfVbmeOJvv4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

- Saved <s>a byte</s> two bytes thanks to [Rogem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77406/rogem).

```c
s=1;f(x,y){printf("%d ",s*x),s=x-y?f(-y,~x,s=-s):1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsIwEADP5hUlVtiVXWjEeDAU3yJpIzkYSlMhodSvR23xNDOHsfywtpTYKuMgUcZ5GH2YHMhDV0mKx4QU28T55oAzvdO3OOJVmaXsu9750Ff1Om47Da8pgpRoxPPuA@AsdjWc6YI/KtIrWZH6y2kT3ZBuUCzlAw)

Answer (score 1):

## C#(Visual C# Interactive Compiler), 62 bytes

```
void a(int i,int j){Write((j-i)%2==0?i++:j--);if(i<=j)a(i,j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P@/LD8zRSFRIzOvRCFTB0RmaVaHF2WWpGpoZOlmaqoa2doa2Gdqa1tl6epqWmemaWTa2GZpAjXoZGla1/5P1DDUMdW0/g8A)

Comment: I think you need a separator.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 22 bytes

```
IIT}:nP}:nM2K(?t2K=?h;
```

Fixed!!!
It had a major bug where it would sometimes append a zero when not necessary, but no longer!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MzpNYqLwCIfY28NexLjLxt7TOs//831DEFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
≔…·ＮＮθＷθ«≔⮌θθ⟦Ｉ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DMy85p7Q4syw1KDEvPRXILSgt8SvNTUot0tDUUUDhAvmFmtZc5RmZOakKGoWaCtVcnFBTglLLUouKU4GCEDWcAUWZeSUa0c6JxSUaAfkFQIlYoHDt//@GCqb/dctyEgE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔…·ＮＮθ
```

Create an inclusive range between the two inputs.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until it is empty.

```
≔⮌θθ
```

Reverse it.

```
⟦Ｉ⊟θ
```

Remove the last element and print it on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{flat($_ Z [R,] $_)[^*/2]}o&[..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzotJ7FEQyVeIUohOkgnVkElXjM6TkvfKLY2Xy1aTy/2vzVXcWKlQpqGiY6ZJoxtqGMKZ@sa6hgiOKYGOqYGmtb/AQ)

Not too complicated, but there's a couple of tricks that help make the program shorter

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                        }o&[..]   # Convert the two inputs to a range
      $_ Z [R,] $_                 # Zip the range with its reverse
 flat(            )                # Flatten
                   [^*/2]          # And take the first half of the elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>93</del> <del>92</del> 81 bytes

Standalone program, **81 bytes**:

```php
for($a=range($argv[1],$argv[2]);$a;)echo$x++%2?array_pop($a):array_shift($a),' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbYsS89JTgYyi9LJow1gdCMMoVtNaJdFaMzU5I1@lQltb1cg@sagosTK@IL8AqFbTCsIrzshMKwHxddQV1K3///9v@N8UAA)

As a function, **92 bytes**:

```php
function($l,$h){for($a=range($l,$h);$a;)$b[]=$x++%2?array_pop($a):array_shift($a);return$b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZdJNi5xAEAbg@/yK99BhlbVm7epuP9YMewrkEMiS6zAs7qBxwqKiDiSE/PbJ62YC@YAHtK2y2q5y7MbL24exG2HaucUOl/bcH5fT0EfmJTFd/L0dpsjUu6nuPzfXZ5Wpq9g87w878/X29o0@1NNUf3sah5GZ8f2v1dyd2mVdV1OznKfePFc/LtVmY5ZmXmbutN8Ae59khwTA3R0@NfP5ZbmHR4awxmwS/o1ZBCgz3BoXm9g14Y@4WKak16D@H1SksK/hkCYhPfwVDilIfAkSX4DE5yDxGUh8AIn3IPEOJJ5fpLxYkPgUJK4EiStA4nKQuAwkLoDE8Rys4hxInILEWZC4FCRagkQLkGgOEs1AomwFq6gHiTqQqIJEeVRW0RQktgSJLUBic5DYDCQ2gMR6kFgHEqsgsewmq1j2jFVKsEYBVsjB9zOOSQLWbmA9Bdbdob9HcOCo@es09bGLcJ15PfMOMfvfHLsBX4ZTH93gJnn996LtdmuWOE7w@P7x6d3HDyxw@Qk)

```php
function ( $l, $h ) {
    for( $a = range( $l, $h ); $a; ) {
        $b[] = $x++ % 2 ? array_pop( $a ) : array_shift( $a );
    }
    return $b;
}
```

Well, I thought it was a worth-trying idea.  Perhaps in a more succinct language, this would work better.  The Golf is not strong with this one.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>b=>a+[,a-b?f(b)(a<b?a+1:a-1):[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADA7@xiBh68SOpDxMOuaRSikdH3beaij0Z6zvuVre95zmLJOraORFhIsi/ACLSxJ6EMSYUmxDhTb6PXvNZ@QAGpETTi/AE)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

Translation of [@nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179877/78960).

```fs
fun a b->let rec h=function|a::b->[a]@h(List.rev b)|n->n in h[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rc2xCsIwFIXh3ac4FIRk6MUOOhQMuvsGpUMaExqQG0mjtJB3j@k7eMbvDL9bWhOiLcV9GBpTq142IVqD@VrJJB84676vx6DH2ywefkkU7ReTzNwqhmfMgyaaxuJCxLpDR3TGM2CHbYcLUXeqckDdO3pOjtEc7w3ElpVYs/pDX8ryAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Shortcuts for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334?mt=8), 20 Actions, 4 KB

Shortcuts is a visual scripting language, so the code is linked as a screenshot and download.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9CN6.png) (very tall) / [Shortcut iCloud link](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/d67874e5d84347a3a4ab0e9d27109d44)

How it works:

```
getVariable (input.s)
if Equals (input.s)
```

This tests if input.s exists. input.s will be nothing if it does not exist. In shortcuts, nothing does not equal itself.

```
otherwise
```

There is no way to test for not equal in shortcuts other than using the else side of an if statement

```
dictionary {a:input.a, b:input.b, c:1}
setVariable (input)
```

To set a single key in a dictionary, you need to get the variable, set dictionary value, and re-set the variable. Creating a new dictionary here saves one action but takes more bytes. I am optimizing for actions here.

```
getVariable (input.a)
if Equals (input.b)
  getVariable(input.a)
otherwise
```

If both a and b are the same, this range only has one value. Values passed to otherwise are returned by End, similar to how ternary operators work in many languages.

```
number 0
calculate - (input.s)
getVariable (input.a)
calculate + (input.s)
```

No set variable is required because instead, magic variables are used to get the values from the calculate actions

```
dictionary{a: input.b, b:(Calculation Result), c: (Calculation Result)}
```

The two calculation results refer to different actions. The first to the a+s, and the second to the 0-s.

```
runShortcut ch-arrangement
```

Run this shortcut again with the new input and return the result.

To run, pass a dictionary containing a and b to the shortcut. Output is the list as a string (comma seperated). [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKIct.png) / [Link](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/586db95924704684a6564e73091d5e08)

There is no online interpreter for this. You need an iOS device and the [Shortcuts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334?mt=8) app.

Logic from [@ovs's javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179921/77796)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 62 bytes

```
#(distinct(let[r(range %1(inc %2))](interleave r(reverse r)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwDIbP7VMEZJAeButwHn2R0kPZokxiO7pu4NPXTEEwhHx/8h/@jJweW6ZacaIbrIm3Mqeo9QmneS1zHAsyFZcxh3gnaCzKDZreGC@qUGYKO4H4tFNeRRkpraVxSoFZK2yvV3DuDBcPzsIgs7Vgv@gPDB0MnfdaKXyGRaAkPh1UuGSJ4QiN@d8xLAu/fh@L/6la3w)

Wow Clojure is a terrible golfing language. Still fun though.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 62 bytes

Using immediate window and [a1] and [a2] as input.

```
a=[a1]:b=[a2]:For x=0To(b-a)/2:?a+x &IIf(b-x=a+x,"",b-x);:Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
[:(#$],@,.|.)[+i.@>:@-~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600lFVidRx09Gr0NKO1M/Uc7KwcdOv@a3KlJmfkK8QbKaQpGEHYBkCmKYRpCGQaGv4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

**C (compiled with VC++ (Visual Studio 2017)) 264bytes**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void f(int l,int u){for(int t=1,h=0,H=0,i=0;i<u-l+1;i++,t^=1)printf("%d ",t?l+h++:u-H++);}void main(){f(1,5);}
```

choosing other Compiler may eliminate the Need for the include but vs2017 won't let me ommit it w/o Errors.
the idea is to just use variables to Keep track of how many numbers have to be added to the Minimum or have to be subtracted from the maximum (2seperate variables)
another variable is used to Keep track of from where the value has to be taken from front or from end. Setting it to 1 means lowest bit is set xor-ing it with 1 makes it toggle.
i run a loop with the amount of iterations it takes to solve the Problem.
inside the printf i use the Array Bounds and my variables to generate the number needed and increment my helper variables all at once. using the ternary Operator exp?then:else saves a few Bytes as it replaces a if-else Statement. further saving come through use of multiple variables defined in the for loop instead of only one (typically i) and putting the xor in the loop Header removes the Need for curly braces.

every Thing else i did is ommit spaces and linebreaks where possible and only use 1 character variable names and omitting ()s where ever possible

Comment: tested only with Bounds 1 and 5 but should work w/ everything else as well

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8 (JDK)**: 113, 98, **124** bytes

```
(l,h)->{String s="";while(h>=l)s+=l+++" "+h--+" ";return s.substring(0,s.length()-(l-h==2?(l+(l<0?".":"")).length()+2:1));};
```

Thanka to Sriotchilism O'Zaic and Embodiment of Ignorance for saving me 15 bytes! Unfortunately those bytes were used to fix a bug Jo King mentioned. 

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jYyxboMwFEV3vsJisoVtQVo6lJpI6dShU8aqg0MMNjUG4edUFeLbKUqjDpWqZLpP9517WnmSrD1@LEM4WFOhykrv0as0booulQcJa5x6c0Td@sB7GI1r3t4lmaJ23fMAxvI6uApM7/jOPPfOh06NTy8OVKNGeskS1UigBVuqCSunHw/yIo6LT22swroUlvhEYJskJIlRnGDN2Pkq9l8eVMf7AHxYd4A99@Hgzw6cUs@tcg1oTBi2TAux2d49poSQYi6WmsuqUgPge/pAiuivyjq8tr9QRvPrEMtodhO1uYHKU5qn/3LRPC/f)

My first every golf code submission. Code is a functional interface that takes 2 integers and builds a string from those integers. The substring hack at the end hides a little quirk that duplicates the last element of the "array." Probably not the best solution, but for my first ever submission, I think I did well :)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I haven't programmed very much in java, but this is a lambda right?  Would it maybe be shorter to return the result rather than output it?  `System.out.print` seems very long.

Comment: Also, you can golf two bytes by removing the parens around `l++` and `h++`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYyxT4QwHIV3/oqGqQ1tA6c4iOWSc3JwutE49LhCi6UQfu0ZQ/jbEfXiYGLuppe8932vlSfJ2uPbMoSDNRWqrARAz9K4KTpX4KVf49SbI@rWAe/9aFzz8irJFLWrz4M3ltfBVd70ju/MY@8gdGp8eHJeNWqk5yxRjQRasKWasHL6@UEg4rh418YqrEthCSTCJkkSozjRjH1lsf8ArzreB8@H1fEYOIQDfPs4pcCtco3XmDBsmRZis725TwkhxVwsNZdVpQaPb@kdKaK/V9bhtf2FMppfhlhGs6uozRVUntI8/ZeL5nn5BA "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 20 bytes

```
:{:&=?v:1+&}
  oanr/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36raSs3WvszKUFutlktBIT8xr0j/////umUKpiBC1xQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 95 bytes

```
	A =INPUT
	B =INPUT
L	OUTPUT =LE(A,B) A	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =GT(B,A) B
	A =A + 1
	B =B - 1	:(L)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NRwdbTLyA0hIvTCcby4fQPDQEyFGx9XDUcdZw0FRw5rdw0XP1cNLngUu4hGk46jpoKTlwgIxwVtBUMwUY4KegqGHJaafhocgE1/P9vyGUOAA)

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Python 3.5, 123 bytes

Script takes two params: interval from, interval to.

```python
from sys import*;v=[*range(int(argv[1]),int(argv[2])+1)];o=[]
for i in range(len(v)):v.reverse();o.append(v.pop())
print(o)
```

example:

```python
$ ./script.py 1 5
[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]

$ ./script.py -5 6
[-5, 6, -4, 5, -3, 4, -2, 3, -1, 2, 0, 1]
```

### Explanation

```python
# create range input params
v=[*range(int(argv[1]),int(argv[2])+1)]

# define ampty output array
o=[]

# loop input-array-lenght times
for i in range(len(v)):

    # reverse input array
    v.reverse()

    # append last input element to output
    o.append(v.pop())

# print output array
print(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
‹rI÷ṘY
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oC5cknDt+G5mFkiLCIiLCItNTAsNTAiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
‹rI÷ṘY
‹      # decrement
 r     # range
  I÷   # split into two halves
    Ṙ  # reverse
     Y # interleave
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IḲIU
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyzwf7tjkGbqkOCm5GCq0YJmpAZeuqQGEBwA)

Takes the upper number first.

##### Explanation

```python
IḲIU  # Implicit input
I     # Inclusive range between the two inputs
 Ḳ    # Bifurcate: reverse a copy
  I   # Interleave them together
   U  # Uniquify the list
      # Implicit output
```