# First odd then even indices

Tags: code-golf, permutations

Your task is to find out how often you need to "shuffle" a given list with the following operation until you get back the original list.

```
start with a list:
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 
split it into the elements at odd and even indices
(1 3 5 7 9) (2 4 6 8)
concatenate these two list
(1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8)
```

Input: A list

Output: The number of iterations it takes until you get back the original list

### Examples

```
(1 2 3) -> (1 3 2) -> (1 2 3)               => 2
(1 2 3 4 3 2 1) -> (1 3 3 1 2 4 2) -> ...   => 3
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) -> ...               => 6
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) -> ...            => 10
"abab" -> "aabb" -> "abab"                  => 2
"Hello, World!" -> "Hlo ol!el,Wrd" -> ...   => 12
(1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1) -> ...                => 6
(1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1) -> ...              => 10
(1 1 1 1 1 1 1) -> (1 1 1 1 1 1 1)          => 1
```

### Rules

- You can use lists of any type (that supports at least two distinct values)
- You can assume the the list has at least two elements
- The odd/even indices are determined using 1-based indexing
- You have to apply the operation at least once
- If your language has a built-in for finding fixed points consider adding a non-builtin solution as well
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution (per language) wins

Comment: Can we assume that the list has more than one element?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82294/faro-shuffle-an-array)

Answer (score 8):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
#{x@<2!!#x}\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1KurnCwMVJUVK6ojeHiSos2VDBSMI6FMRRMgNhIwRBZwFTBTMFcwULBUsHQAJe4giFYi1JiUmKSEpjlkZqTk6+jEJ5flJOiqATRB1SmACINoCxDmDCUC5UygEkgwVgA6yonqg==)

`{ ... }\` Iterate until reaching the first value again (or a fixed point). Collect intermediate values.
`2!!#x` 2 mod range of length *x*. Sequence of alternating 0s and 1s the same length as *x*.
`x@<` Grade up, then index into *x*. Sorts *x* by that sequence.

`#` Length. Counts the number of intermediate results.

Comment: "Iterate until reaching the first value again (or a fixed point)" -- Looks like the K builtin is much nicer than J's here.  In J, only consecutive repeats count as a fixed point.  In K, it sounds like at minimum "repeat consecutive" and "repeat first" trigger a break.  What about "repeat some other intermediate value, but not consecitively"?  Ie, stop when you see _any_ previous value a 2nd time? (this makes the most sense to me)

Comment: @Jonah intermediate values are not checked, which can be a pain when cycles don't include the initial value. I think the justification is that quadratic complexity could be unwanted/unexpected

Comment: Right.  Ideally, it would be configurable (via an adverb perhaps in J-land), and you could even configure the check to use something like a hash table.

Answer (score 8):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
µ¥zS
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDMiVBNXpTJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MSUyQzIlMkMzJTJDNCUyQzUlMkM2JTJDNyUyQzglMkM5JTJDMTAmZmxhZ3M9TA==) or [verify all test cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDMiVBNXpTJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTVCMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTVEJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMiUwQSU1QjElMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDQlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDElNUQlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAzJTBBJTVCMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDUlMkMlMjA2JTJDJTIwNyUyQyUyMDglMkMlMjA5JTJDJTIwMTAlNUQlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjA2JTBBJTVCMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDUlMkMlMjA2JTJDJTIwNyUyQyUyMDglMkMlMjA5JTJDJTIwMTAlMkMlMjAxMSU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDEwJTBBJTVCMSUyQyUyMDAlMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDAlMkMlMjAwJTJDJTIwMCUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDYlMEElNUIxJTJDJTIwMCUyQyUyMDAlMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAwJTJDJTIwMCUyQyUyMDAlMkMlMjAwJTJDJTIwMSU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDEwJTBBJTVCMSUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSU1RCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDElMEElMjJhYmFiJTIyJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMiUwQSUyMkhlbGxvJTJDJTIwV29ybGQhJTIyJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMTImZmxhZ3M9Q0w=)

```
µ¥zḞ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDMiVBNXolRTElQjglOUUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDMiUyQzMlMkM0JTJDNSUyQzYlMkM3JTJDOCUyQzklMkMxMCZmbGFncz1M) or [verify all test cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

```
µ¥^ḥ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDMiVBNSU1RSVFMSVCOCVBNSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTElMkMyJTJDMyUyQzQlMkM1JTJDNiUyQzclMkM4JTJDOSUyQzEwJmZsYWdzPUw=) or [verify all test cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

---

> Don't worry, the stack languages with single-byte uninterleave operators are going to be even shorter :P

lol

##### Explanation

```python
      # Implicit input

µ¥    # Collect while unique:

  z   #  Uninterleave into two pieces
      #   [1,2,3,4,5,6]  ->  [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
   S  #  Then flatten the nested list
      #   [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]  ->  [1,3,5,2,4,6]
   Ḟ  #  Alternative flatten built-in
      #   [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]  ->  [1,3,5,2,4,6]

  ^   #  Or, uninterleave and push separately
      #   [1,2,3,4,5,6]  ->  [1,3,5] [2,4,6]
   ḥ  #  Then concatenate the two lists
      #   [1,3,5] [2,4,6]  ->  [1,3,5,2,4,6]

      # Finally, the L flag takes the length
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>26</s></sup> 24 bytes

```
i.~_:0}(\:2|#\)^:(3<@^#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvLCoJQEIb3PcVPgpfI8RztOmRIQato0VaPEpFmm14gfXU7mWIxzDAz3/c/mjFZOUKGhSkEWLdL2J@Ph6akOmNR2Qn7LyNxUraDTZQaTuOMTjuCxrIilZm2Up1St0JLYzZUESkdkq7LOnzhIiRPeyVFvTIhT3vm1txTzB6jg7fr/YkcEj6CvwMzzLHAEiusIcXAhO7PFN0mB/RT/VN8E80b)

Accepts numeric lists

The maximum number of iterations until we return to the input is bounded by [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) \$g(n)\$, and it can be shown that:

$$
{\displaystyle g(n)\leq e^{n/e}}
$$

For golf reasons, I simply round that to:

$$
{\displaystyle g(n)\leq 3^{n}}
$$

and iterate that many times.  Note I could trade bytes for efficiency here and iterate until I see the input again, but this approach was shorter.

- `(\:2|#\)` Apply the needed permutation -- equivalent to sorting down by `1 0 1 0...`
- `^:(3<@^#)` Do that \$3^n\$ times, saving results
- `_:0}` Convert the first item on the list, which is the input itself, to infinity, so that match will be skipped.
- `i.~` Index of the input within that list.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒœẎ$ƬL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKOTH@7qUzm2xuf/4XbNyP//o6MNdRSMdBSMY3W4YEwdBRMwCWQbogub6iiY6SiY6yhY6ChYAuUNCCoAYpApSolJiUlKQNoD6JR8HYXw/KKcFEUliG6QIjAygCEIF2Y9ihiSKgOEEnQUGwsA)

Don't worry, the stack languages with single-byte uninterleave operators are going to be even shorter :P

```
    Ƭ     Repeat while unique, collecting all results:
Œœ        Split into odd and even-indexed elements,
  Ẏ$      and concatenate.
     L    How many results are there?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
vDÅ≠})Ùg
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/zOVw66POBbWah2em//8fbahjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY2gQCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/zKXcztPz6nVPDwz/b/O/@hoQx0jHeNYHQitYwLERjqGSHxTHTMdcx0LHUsdQwMcwjqGIA1KiUo6SklADKFBIh5AVioQ50BxPhCDoAIQh0P5RVC5FCBWVALbADRQB0QaQFmGUFEoDypjABVHgrGxAA) (the test suite uses the faster alternative `ι˜` instead of `Å≠`).

**Explanation:**

Although 05AB1E has an unshuffle builtin `Å≠` (even though `ι˜` does the same and is faster..), it unfortunately lacks a "*Repeat until unique*" builtin..

```python
v     # Loop the (implicit) input-length amount of times:
 D    #  Duplicate the current list
      #  (which will be the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
  Å≠  #  Unshuffle it
})    # After the loop: wrap all lists on the stack into a list
  Ù   # Uniquify this list of lists
   g  # Pop and push its length
      # (which is output implicitly as result)

  ι   #  Uninterleave it into a pair of lists
   ˜  #  Flatten it to a single list
```

Answer (score 5):

## Google Sheets, 107 bytes

`=let(d,torow(A:A,3),_,lambda(_,a,n,sort(let(b,torow(wrapcols(a,2),3),if(and(b=d),n,_(_,b,1+n))))),_(_,d,1))`

Put the input in cells `A1:A` and the formula in `B1`.

The formula is self-contained. Uses *singularize(wrap())* like the [Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264442/119296) but does not depend on named functions or named ranges.

[Try it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P8-wj-Zkf0bw7PgVKYAbs53JNxvvQCaXgfNOROHGWWQ/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 65 bytes

```python
lambda s,j=1:j*((t:=s[:len(s)-1|1])==(t*2**j)[::2**j])or f(s,j+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZHdToMwFMfjLU9xxlWLhVCYc5LUxLu9wS5wWYqDyNJRQmuyJb6JN0uMvoRPok9jC8wNnW1STs_5_85HeXmvd_pRVvvXgt2_PenCn37eCb7JVhwUWTOarD2EdMJUmoi8Qgr79JkuMGNIe5HnrXGaJPa7wLKBAhnmkuI-0VthfFsoK5C1YUOcOFASCQy2gapFqZEL7BZc7IB1lpVGElvJkiztPah5o0tdysoI_U6o2oDSTVkjnNLEpwsHdLNLQLHU2_AamTRE9fkxNtF8-5DXuhMoc68bW0kR0y0msm92_3XxgShEEGNbypgxRAez9Q6X6TtyuhCMrRboEYzBBsZ9giAIOiA-AlcwgWuYwg3Q8ET0q8LkPACUnmMMQEPH5RnPuufiPDtYre_PaodwZ7kQksBcNmI16vQzIUGKUS7IvFm5gyFoO7bpAewZ9tbZhk6n-BH2UPgf0k2BKJzsw8sOXAOi-4nf)

### How?

This is based on the observation that in zero-based indexing the  reshuffle can be written as n -> 2n mod N where N is the largest odd number not greater than the length of the input. (If the length is even the last point is a fixed point, so it can be ignored.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 6 bytes

```
ᶦ{ĭ,ᵖ≠
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FmsfbltWfWStzsOt0x51LlhSnJRcDJVZcHNutKGOkY5xLBeE1jEBYiMdQyS-qY6ZjrmOhY6ljqEBDmEdQ6AGpcSkxCQlLiWP1JycfB2F8PyinBRFJZAGoLwOiDSAsiCmw3lQGQOoOBKMhbgSAA)

Nekomata has a single-byte uninterleave operator, but still can't beat Jelly, because it doesn't have a "repeat while unique" operator.

```
ᶦ{ĭ,ᵖ≠
ᶦ{          Repeat until failure:
  ĭ             Uniterleave
   ,            Join
    ᵖ≠          Check if the result is unequal to the input
```

`-n` counts the number of iterations.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 31 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.875 bytes

```
yJ)↲
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJ+bD0iLCIiLCJ5SinihrIiLCIiLCJbMSwgMiwgM10gPT4gMlxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDMsIDIsIDFdID0+IDNcblsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMF0gPT4gNlxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDgsIDksIDEwLCAxMV0gPT4gMTBcblsxLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAxXSA9PiA2XG5bMSwgMCwgMCwgMSwgMSwgMSwgMCwgMCwgMCwgMCwgMV0gPT4gMTBcblsxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxXSA9PiAxXG5cImFiYWJcIiA9PiAyXG5cIkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCFcIiA9PiAxMiJd)

> the stack languages with single-byte uninterleave operators are going to be even shorter

~ some jelly answer, probably

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 93 bytes

Define:

`a` as `=$A$1#` (*7 bytes*)

`z` as `=LAMBDA(p,q,LET(x,TOCOL(WRAPROWS(p,2),2,1),y,q+1,IF(SUM(N(x<>a))=0,y,z(x,y))))` (*79 bytes*)

Within the worksheet: `=z(a,0)` (*7 bytes*)

`$A$1#` is a spilled, *vertical* range comprising the list entries.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 70 bytes

```r
f=\(x,l=0,y=c(x[!0:1],x[!1:0]),`-`=list)`if`(-y%in%l,0,1+f(y,c(l,-y)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU5LCsIwFDyLi8J7OIG81oUEsvUSWogUA4GgxUZozuImLnoob2OKXcxnMTPM-_Msi3-km11eyavj9-TthWZEq5HtQPN5p430qCpG9wynnI1hSuyCd6RyE-5NhIbsPWUMFKEyM29rMl3HMWZaGySmqwFBiw6HihbCECN6pWrXG1uxlL_-AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
->l{k=*l;1.step.find{w=-2;l==k=k.map{k[w+=2]||k[w=1]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbRCsIgFAbgV9l1/UrHVivk9CLiRaOE0IW0DRnqs9u@q@@3jltz3MQjZM@HoEnOyztK9/m@cmKhdGD27OX0jNmbdGRlS9nDZGutLXbOGILCGT0uuGLADXfQCUTWtj8)

Comment: -1 byte by upgrading to 2.6 for endless range. Also, since you're reassigning instead of modifying `k` you can skip the splat and just do a shallow assignment at the start. [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsHiNNuYpaUlaboWN0117XKqs21zrDUM9fQ09dIy81Kqy211jaxzbG2zbbP1chMLqrOjy7VtjWJraoAMW8PY2tpaiOZ9BQpp0dGGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmOhY6ljqGBjqGhrGxEEULFkBoAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```r
\(x,y=x){while(sd((y[]=matrix(y,2,,T))-x))T=T+1;+T}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZLBToQwEEATj37FLF7a7EBo2V0xpnte7yR7UA8gEDepNkGMEOOXeEETP0q_xkLZtaCrF9uhTBveyzDw_FI0r7l4uy9zN3wPLkiFtajo48P1RmbkLiWkPr8UN3FZbCpSI0eMKHUrSiMRTdnpNHoy6MeBzMkVYQgcIaD0CNwlEAYBcNqnXJ_DcIgl8EOLQ5h1q86Z7QigxWe9y_M8wwb_ys4RFgjHCCHCiZb4vcUgo7IXf-P6Yj8rNM98LdCdCyN1dlsSJ07ixOmfduI4SRyTtcfwbfR9s_hVJqVCWKtCppOdaCUVKDnJJK6L1Bm8P9s1vi20C38bZrun-HEDBogl8X8xbBvQCcbx9fGsSYew-emaxtw_AQ)

Comment: Nice!  What on earth was I thinking collecting all the intermediate values...?  Doh!  Well done.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZJBT4MwFIATj_6KN7y02YPQwibGsPO8k-ygHoqDuKSuCcEIMf4SL2jij9JfY6FsFtR5sX2U14bvy-PB80vRvObx232Zu9F7eEUqrOOKPj7cbmRGxLYmpL68ju9EWWwqUiNHTCh1K0qTOJmy82nyZNiPI5mTG8IQOEJA6Qm4CyAMAuC0T7k-h-GIF8CPLQ4h7FadM9sRQIuHvcvzPMMG_8rOEOYIpwgRwpmW-L3FIKOy53_j-mI_KzTPfC3QnYsSdbEtiSNSkTr9044QaeqYrD2Gb6Pvm8UvMykVwkoVcj3Zi5ZSgZKTTOKqWDuD92f7xreFduHvwmx_KX7cgAFiSfwDhl0DOsE4vj6eNekQNj9d05j7Jw)...

Comment: [51 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZLBToQwEEATj37FLF7a7EBo2V0xpnte7yR7UA8gEDepNkGMEOOXeEETP0q_xkLZtaCrF9uhTBveyzDw_FI0r7l4uy9zN3wPLkiFtajo48P1RmbkLiWkPr8UN3FZbCpSI0eMKHUrSiMRTdnpNHoy6MeBzMkVYQgcIaD0CNwlEAYBcNqnXJ_DcIgl8EOLQ5h1q86Z7QigxWe9y_M8wwb_ys4RFgjHCCHCiZb4vcUgo7IXf-P6Yj8rNM98LdCdCyN1dlsSJ07ixOmfduI4SRyTtcfwbfR9s_hVJqVCWKtCppOdaCUVKDnJJK6L1Bm8P9s1vi20C38bZrun-HEDBogl8X8xbBvQCcbx9fGsSYew-emaxtw_AQ)...(```y-x``` can never be all-the-same unless it's all-zero, I think...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice observation!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
⊞υθＷ‹№υθ²⊞υ⭆²Φ§υ±¹﹪⁺κν²Ｉ⊖Ｌυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xC8IwEEb3/opzu0Ac7OokFVGwUnBwDs3RFs9Ek4v672O0OH/ve68fTei94Zy7FEdMGh5qXb3GiQnwSDFi45OTedBQKwV/8CxhckNr7lhr2E0sFHAjB2fp/Z1PNBghXKlya71N7LHjFPGqwc0mVUpdcQg2JgpuqQ90IydkS9kNUio/KOc9MXsNFx/YLqq8fPIH) Link is to verbose version of code. Only works on strings. Explanation:

```
⊞υθ
```

Push the string to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｗ‹№υθ²
```

Repeat until a second copy of the string is found.

```
⊞υ⭆²Φ§υ±¹﹪⁺κν²
```

Shuffle the most recent string and push it to the list.

```
Ｉ⊖Ｌυ
```

Output the number of shuffles taken.

28 bytes to work on strings or lists:

```
⊞υθＷ‹№υθ²⊞υΣＥ²Φ§υ±¹﹪⁺κν²Ｉ⊖Ｌυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjdnBpQWZ2iU6igUalpzlWdk5qQqaPikFhdrOOeX5pVAJHQUjDQ1FWAKg0tzNXwTCzSMdBTcMnNKUos0HEs881JSK0CSfqnpiSWpGoaaQE2--SmlOfkaATmlxRrZOgp5EHOAwJoroCgTaLhzYnGJhktqclFqbmpeSWoK0OK89BKgJWBFS4qTkouhzlweraRblqMUuyM62hBoio6CsY6CCZgEsg1jY7kgygA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

Expects a list of positive integers.

```javascript
a=>(g=a=>(g[a]^=i=-2)&&1+g(a.map(_=>a[!a[i+=2]|i%a.length])))(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY3LDoIwEEX3fkVdSNowEFvxtSg/0qCZINQapESIK/@9VlxIiMSYzNzM49zcC96xzW@m6aLangpXSocypVr2qjA7SCMjwYKAh5pifMWGHmWKao7KhFJkD7PAuCpq3Z0zxhhF5nJbt7Yq4spqWlLF/X02vgERQFbTHyBJr37mP6g1kA2QLZAdkL3Hl//yvr9lvKJ723vgg1VM4h9kYOKTjnF5yj0B)

#### How?

We can apply the shuffle by doing:

```javascript
a.map((_, i) => a[!a[i * 2] | i * 2 % a.length])
```

This code first collects all values at even (0-based) indices. When `a[i * 2]` is not defined anymore, it starts collecting values at odd indices.

For golfing reasons, we rather start with \$i=-2\$ and do:

```javascript
a.map(_ => a[!a[i += 2] | i % a.length])
```

We stop as soon as the same array has been encountered twice and return the number of iterations.

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 45 bytes

```
=$a $a"2/` tpose flat"itr1dp"$a !=`"tk* len1+
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Takes a list.

For testing purposes:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11] ;
=$a $a"2/` tpose flat"itr1dp"$a !=`"tk* len1+
```

NOTE: for string-based inputs, use e.g. `["a" "b" "a" "b"]`.

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
=$a $a.
( 2/` tpose flat ) itr 1dp ( $a !=` ) tk* len 1+
```

- `=$a $a` Input list *a*
- `(...) itr` generate infinite list from successive modifications of *a*...

  - `` 2/` tpose flat `` chunk into pairs, transpose, flatten
- `1dp` drop first item to prevent `tk*` from exiting early
- `` ( $a !=` ) tk* `` take while not equal to *a*
- `len 1+` length + 1

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 49 bytes

```arturo
$->a[1x:a while[i:0arrange'x=>[i%2'i+1]x<>a][1+]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yigxrb)

```
$->a[                         ; a function taking an input a
    1                         ; push 1 -- this is our output (count)
    x:a                       ; assign a to x
    while[                    ; while...
        i:0                   ; assign 0 to i
        arrange'x=>[i%2'i+1]  ; sort x by its indices' parities
        x<>a                  ; x doesn't equal a...
    ]                         ; end while predicate
    [1+]                      ; ...then increment the output
]                             ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
o(x:s)=x:e s
o _=[]
e=o.drop 1
a!b|a==b=1|0<1=1+a!(o b++e b)
f a=a!(o a++e a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc6xCsIwEAbgPU9xKQ4JtWLW4HUT9AkcisiFplpaezXt0KHvHqsoiMvx8/3wczcaGt@2ka0t6JzlyxH@Jyuprd0/gABz@GqWH7vRX30Q1V/58chqsoPGyXoYBMMFi2UWeVMG7sEIkm4mRIdm3u4MmpSkYnBp6sFpUQHhG@gFpOOd6g4Q@lB3I6xAVZAclqd5DScObSkTHZ8)